# Slight occlusion lead to inaccurate corner location when detect ArUco Markers

Tags: opencv, aruco

Those occluded marker should be filtered out, but `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` return the marker with incorrect corner location.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set a lower `polygonalApproxAccuracyRate` fixed the issue, which will filter those markers with inaccurate corners.

The default value of `polygonalApproxAccuracyRate` is 0.03, I change to 0.008

```
parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
parameters.polygonalApproxAccuracyRate = 0.008
result = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(
            gray, cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco_dict_idx), parameters=parameters
        )
```